# XSD-1.1 command line validation tool for Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, file-format, xml

I'm looking for a command line tool to validate an XML file with an XSD-1.1 file.

I have downloaded and installed `libxerces2-java` and then tried to apply [Free and open source XSD 1.1 validation tool?](https://jeszysblog.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/free-and-open-source-xsd-1-1-validation-tool/)  and [Xerces validator in command line](http://jmvanel.free.fr/xsd/README.html), but I couldn't get either of them to work.

**So, my simple question is:**
Where can I get/how can I create an XSD-1.1 validating tool that can be run from the command line to validate an XML file?
Please provide a full solution, because Java class paths and so on are a topic of their own...

Answer (score 2):

*Finally* I found an answer to my own question:
I found the blog post ["Free and open source XSD 1.1 validation tool?"](https://jeszysblog.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/free-and-open-source-xsd-1-1-validation-tool/)
which contains a link to the file [xsd11-validator.jar](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10564628/xsd11-validator.jar) ([Mirror 1](https://www.load.to/giPz2MvUAe/xsd11-validator.jar), [Mirror 2](https://workupload.com/file/khtLRPtE)).

You can call it like this:

```
usage: java hu.unideb.inf.validator.SchemaValidator -if <file> | -iu <url>
       [-sf <file> | -su <url>]
 -if,--instanceFile <file>   read instance from the file specified
 -iu,--instanceUrl <url>     read instance from the URL specified
 -sf,--schemaFile <file>     read schema from the file specified
 -su,--schemaUrl <url>       read schema from the URL specified
```

To run it, you can use the following command line:

```
java -jar xsd11-validator.jar -sf schema.xsd -if instance.xml
```

---

And to simplify its usage, I wrote the following bash script `xsd.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "======== XSD 1.1 Validator (for local files) ========";
  echo "=====================================================";
  echo "Usage: xsd.sh XSDschemaFile.xsd XMLFileToValidate.xml";
  echo "=====================================================";
  echo "(To validate remote files you have to call xsd11-validator.jar directly)";
else
  output=$( java -jar xsd11-validator.jar -sf $1 -if $2 2>&1 )
  if [ -z "$output" ]
  then
    echo "=== Validation succeeded! ===";
    exit 0
  else
    echo "=== Validation FAILED! ===";
    echo "$output";
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

It can easily validate XSD-1.1 files with the following command:

```
./xsd.sh schema.xsd input.xml
```